# Rewriting a quadratic Matrix equation as a quadratic vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, block-matrices

Consider the set of $N \times N$ matrices $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^{i=L}$, set of $N \times 1$ vectors $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{i=L}$ and $\{h_i\}_{i=1}^{i=L}$. Now consider the following sum
\begin{align}
S=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}g_i^HW_ih_ih_j^{H}W_j^{H}g_j
\end{align}
where the summation runs through all $L$ for all $i,j$. Clearly, this equation is quadratic in the matrix variables $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^{i=L}$. Now define the column vector
\begin{align}
w=\begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{vec}(W_1) \\ \operatorname{vec}(W_2) \\ \vdots \\ \operatorname{vec}(W_L) \end{bmatrix}
\end{align} 
where for a matrix $A$, $\operatorname{vec}(A)$ denotes the column vector containing the columns of $A$ starting from the first column. The question is, can we write
\begin{align}
S=w^{H}Qw
\end{align}
where $Q$ is a matrix which is a function of $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{i=L}$ and $\{h_i\}_{i=1}^{i=L}$. If so, what is the structure of $Q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}g_i^HW_ih_ih_j^HW_j^Hg_j\\
&=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\operatorname{trace}(g_jg_i^HW_ih_ih_j^HW_j^H)\\
&=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\operatorname{vec}(W_j)^H \operatorname{vec}(g_jg_i^HW_ih_ih_j^H)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\{\because \operatorname{trace}(AB^{H})=\operatorname{trace}(A^{H}B)=\operatorname{vec}(A)^{H}\operatorname{vec}(B)\}\\
& \\
&=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\operatorname{vec}(W_j)^H \left((h_ih_j^H)^T\otimes(g_jg_i^H)\right)\operatorname{vec}(W_i)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\{\because \operatorname{vec}(ABC)=(C^{T}\otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B)\}\\
& \\
&=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\operatorname{vec}(W_j)^H \left((\bar{h}_jh_i^T)\otimes(g_jg_i^H)\right)\operatorname{vec}(W_i)\\
&=w^H Qw,
\end{align}
where $Q$ is a block matrix whose $(j,i)$-th (note: **not** $(i,j)$-th) subblock is $(\bar{h}_jh_i^T)\otimes(g_jg_i^H)$.

Comment: you are always reliable!!!

Comment: @dineshdileep What? Who knows if some mistakes are lurking around in some shadowy places. You should double-check the claimed result.

Comment: I will definitely do that.

Comment: Can you explain (mathematically) the second last step, where you switch to the block matrix. (I almost have it intuitively, but would like to know a rigorous one).

Comment: Let $w_j=\operatorname{vec}(W_j)$. Then $w^T=(w_1^T,\ldots,w_n^T)$. Partition $Q$ into subblocks, each of size $n\times n$. Call the $(j,i)$-th block $Q_{ji}$. Then by $w^HQw=\sum_i\sum_j w_j^H Q_{ji} w_i$. So, by comparing coefficients, we should set $Q_{ji}=(\bar{h}_jh_i^T)\otimes(g_jg_i^H)$.

Comment: hello user1551, I request you to go through this question I am struggling with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654817/convexity-of-a-complicated-function