# SVD for a matrix with a given orthonormal $\mathbf{U}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Let:

1. $\mathbf{A}$ be a $N\times N$ complex matrix.
2. $\mathbf{u}\in \operatorname{span}(\mathbf{A})$ be a given unit norm vector, where $\operatorname{span}(\mathbf{A})$ denotes the column space of $A$.
3. $\mathbf{U}$ be a $N\times N$ unitary matrix whose columns are an orthonormal basis for $\mathbf{A}$ and also its first column is $\mathbf{u}$ (if $\mathbf{A}$ is rank deficient, then the first $r$ columns are a basis for $\mathbf{A}$ and the rest for the null space of $\mathbf{A}$, where $r$ is its rank).

Is there a SVD of $\mathbf{A}$ with the left singular matrix as $\mathbf{U}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You specify only that $\mathbf{u}$ is in the column space of the matrix. That is not enough to be a singular vector.

Comment: What is the additional condition needed? Now I think more about it, $\mathbf{U^HA}$ should be a orthogonal matrix for this to be true. Is it?. But I got it from the definition of SVD. What does it actually imply?

Comment: If $\mathbf{U^HA}$ is orthogonal, then $\mathbf{U^HA}\mathbf{A^HU}$ is diagonal, which would indeed be from the definition of SVD.

Comment: Though the word orthogonal as it is commonly used implies that the diagonal would be ones. That is not true unless all the singular values of A have magnitude one.

Comment: Isn't orthonormal the correct word? I think orthogonal doesn't necessarily mean that gramian matrix is identity? Isn't it so?

Comment: hello adam, I request you to go through this question I am struggling with
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654817/convexity-of-a-complicated-function

Comment: Yes, I agree with your assessment of what orthonormal vs orthogonal should mean. However I have seen multiple discussions lamenting the state of convention: that an orthogonal matrix by definition has vectors which are orthonormal.